# how to nested loop and array in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

> Result of my query from controller

```
date: {2020-09-24: {work_hours: 7}, 2020-09-30: {work_hours: 8}}
2020-09-24: {work_hours: 7}
2020-09-30: {work_hours: 8}
```

> This is my vue I'm trying to nested for loop but I'm getting double
> the result of looping

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <template  v-for="disp in iDate.slice(1)">           
          <th scope="col" v-if="toWordDay(disp.date) == 'Sunday'" style="color:red">{{disp.date | forThDate}}</th>
          <th scope="col" v-else>{{disp.date | forThDate}}</th>
        </template>                           
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template v-for="fetch in attendanceData">
      <tr>
        <template v-for="disp in iDate.slice(1)">                
          <td style="height:10px;"  v-for="(data,ind) in fetch.date" v-if="ind == disp.date" >{{data.work_hours}}</td>  
          <td style="height:10px;" v-else>0</td>                          
        </template>                                  
      </tr>
    </template>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nested for loop suggests nested data ... but your inner for loop has no bearing on the outer for loop - if you have "double data" that implies the outer loop loops twice - without seeing your data though, can't help much

Comment: How can I do that? Can you provide code for that pls

Comment: It's not about nested loops. You're putting 0 in v-else. Remove the td of v-else. It should work Or keep it without any character inside that tag

Comment: not working it will display `7` into `sep 24th`  and `8` into `sep 2th`

Comment: Anyone can help me ? :(

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated my question I put my result of my query

Comment: that doesn't explain what `attendanceData` or `iDate` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `attendanceData` or `iDate`, I'm assuming `fetch.date` is what you mean the `Result of my query from the controller`, which is an object with the dates as keys. You could use `disp.date` as the accessor key.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <template  v-for="disp in iDate.slice(1)">           
          <th scope="col" v-if="toWordDay(disp.date) == 'Sunday'" style="color:red">{{disp.date | forThDate}}</th>
          <th scope="col" v-else>{{disp.date | forThDate}}</th>
        </template>                           
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template v-for="fetch in attendanceData">
      <tr>
        <template v-for="disp in iDate.slice(1)">                
          <td style="height:10px;">
             <template v-if="fetch.date[disp.date]">
               {{fetch.date[disp.date].work_hours || 0}}
             </template> 
             <template v-else>0</template>
          </td>
        </template>                                  
      </tr>
    </template>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It display all 0

Comment: PLS CHECK.. This is same question about this my query is all here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041891/im-trying-to-display-data-in-table-with-relationship-in-table-head-using-larave

Comment: Please add more info about `attendanceData` and `iDate`

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I think I was missing `disp.date`

Comment: I solve this earlier but This is more better than what I did.. Amazing bro thanks :)